# Android vectorDrawableCompact draw vector drawable on top of other vector drawable

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable

I'm using vector drawable support library `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`. I have two vector drawables one is background other is image. I want to place image on background and return **new** bitmap I already have this code (it works perfectly on lollipop and above)

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static android.graphics.Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
        android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(50, 50, canvas.getWidth() - 50, canvas.getHeight() - 50);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

However, I also need this functionality on android kitkat devices. Is that possible. Thanks for your answers

Comment: it will work on kitkat as well, why shouldn't it?

Comment: because of this `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` getIntrinsicWidth for example Call requires API level 21

Comment: ah ok, i missed you are using `VectorDrawable`, use `VectorDrawableCompat` instead